# pandas group by category and assign a bin with pd.cut

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
+-------+-------+
| Group | Price |
+-------+-------+
| A     |     2 |
| B     |     3 |
| A     |     1 |
| C     |     4 |
| B     |     2 |
+-------+-------+
```

I would like to create a column, that would give me the in which range (if I divided each group into 4 intervals) my price value is within each group.

```
+-------+-------+--------------------------+
| Group | Price |          Range           |
+-------+-------+--------------------------+
| A     |     2 |    [1-2]                 |
| B     |     3 |    [2-3]                 |
| A     |     1 |    [0-1]                 |
| C     |     4 |    [0-4]                 |
| B     |     2 |    [0-2]                 |
+-------+-------+--------------------------+
```

Anyone has any idea by using pandas `pd.cut` and `groupby` operations?
Thanks

Comment: Could you [edit] to include the expected output - eg: what the ranges you'd expect here are?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `pd.cut` to `groupby()`:

```
df['Range'] = df.groupby('Group')['Price'].transform(pd.cut, bins=4)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, not sure if it works though as the error `Cannot cast IntervalArray to dtype float64` appears.